# Move a imagen with the keyboard

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a function that can move an image with the `tkinter` library.

Is there a library, except `pygame`, so that I can move an imagen with the keyboard?

Comment: You can place images on a Tkinter canvas and move them around.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an image on a canvas and move it around with the `move` method of the canvas.

Here's a contrived example

```
import tkinter as tk

IMAGE_DATA = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQALMAAAAAAP//AP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQABAAQAQ3UMgpAKC4hm13uJnWgR
    TgceZJllw4pd2Xpagq0WfeYrD7\n2i5Yb+aJyVhFHAmnazE/z4tlSq0KIgA7\n
'''

def move_left(event):
    event.widget.move(image_id, -1, 0)

def move_right(event):
    event.widget.move(image_id, 1, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

image = tk.PhotoImage(data=IMAGE_DATA)
image_id = canvas.create_image(100, 100, anchor="center", image=image)

canvas.bind("<Left>", move_left)
canvas.bind("<Right>", move_right)

canvas.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```